# Windows 7 Phone namspace from silverlight 4 toolkit

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am using the following namepsace in my SL4 project xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
it works fine but when I try using the same in Windows 7 phone app, it says

Unknown namespace http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit. [Line: 20 Position: 10]

Can I use this toolkit in WP7 or not? If yes what change should I be doing?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look in the article, I think it's quite clear about this topic...

*"There is a lot of misinformation out there (even from Microsoft) that the Silverlight 4 Control Toolkit is compatible with the Windows Phone 7 and it's not."*

http://silverlightfeeds.com/post/2502/Windows_Phone_7_RTM_charting_using_the_Silverlight_Control_Toolkit.aspx